# Visual Studio/Xamarin.Auth- java.lang.illegalArgumentException: already added

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

Working with Xamarin.Auth and Visual Studio on an Android Xamarin project... I'm getting the error:
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added : Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat;`

I just recently updated the Xamarin.Auth nuget and that seems to trigger this error, because it disappears when I revert to the old version.

Any tips on how to locate where support.v4 is being added a second time or where it exists in two places?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Xamarin.Auth uses CustomTabs since version 1.4.0. I would suggest bumping all nugets to latest and consolidating them.

Comment: How can I get the CustomTabs to function the same as authenticator.GetUI(activity)?

Comment: also, is there no way to force using nativeui ( isusingnativeui cannot be assigned to -- it is read only)

Comment: @SchwartzBrian There is bool parameter in the ctor called isUsingNativeUI, set it to true). There was setter too, but it was confusing and had no effect. Users were using it in initializer and by the time runtime came to initializer Xamarin.Auth did bunch of stuff in ctors (this() and base()), so initializer had no effect whatsoever.

Here is the link tot the switch in the sample ctor (Xamarin.Forms sample, but this is xplat/shared):
https://github.com/moljac/Xamarin.Auth.Samples.NugetReferences/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms/Evolve16Labs/Portable/MainPage.xaml.cs#L437

Answer (score 0):

Main reason behind this error, is dependency mismatch! i solved by downloading latest API, restart your system(compulsory). And change target version to latest from project properties.

[SDK manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cs5Ab.jpg)